# Execute mysqldump in local machine and fetch the data from the database server behind the server

Tags: linux, port-forwarding, amazon-web-services

I have `EC2` and `RDS` on `AWS`

I want to do mysqldump to fetch the data from `RDS`

My condition are below

- `RDS` accepts the connection from only `EC2` server.
- `EC2` doesn't have the power to use `mysqldump`.

So What I want to do is

running `mysqldump` in my `local machine` and get the data from `RDS` through `EC2`.

I first try to port-forwarding wrongly like this below

```
$ssh -f -N -L 3308:my_rds.amazonaws.com:3306 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa ubuntu@my_ec2.amazonaws.com

$mysqldump -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3308 -pXXXXXX -v mydb > mybackup.sql
```

However, it execute `mysqldump` command on `EC2` server not on `local machine`

I wan to run `mysqldump` in `local machine`

Is it impossible ? or There is some method to do this ??

Thank you very much.

Comment: I corrected my previous answer, the mysqldump runs on your local system. You still havent answered my question about the instance type. You'll need to change your instance type

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the previous answer, mysqldump does run locally on your system but having to maintain an SSH tunnel and push through 9GB of data (and more) is stressing your EC2 instance to the extent that it is running out of CPU Credits and you're being throttled.

Your options:

- resize the existing EC2 instance to a higher class or capacity (maybe a M5/C5 class)
- spin up a new temporary instance of the C5/M5 class and let that be the tunnel
- Spin up a [Fargate task](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/) with a MySQL docker image so that the mysqldump runs on the serverless container and save the dump to S3. Remove when you have a download of it. You can find some sample code and slides for this implementation I did long back on my [Github](https://github.com/SathyaBhat/reinvent-2019-dvc15)